# Which are the devices and browsers that support sitecore 7.2?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

Please tell me which are the devices that support sitecore 7.2, and browsers that support by that devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is [Sitecore Compatibility Table](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/087164)

As you can see there, Sitecore 7.2 is compatible with

- IE9+
- Firefox
- Chrome
- Safari

Comment: Does all the devices support sitecore 7.2

Comment: What do you mean by "support"? Whether you can see Sitecore pages/edit content in Content Editor or Page Editor/something else?